# How to connect to Cassandra with NodeJS using SSL?

Tags: node.js, ssl, cassandra

I've been trying to connect to my Cassandra nodes using SSL option but I can't seem to get it to work. I have all the keystore/truststores setup correctly. Node-to-node encryption works, and client-to-node encryption works through OpsCenter and `cqlsh --ssl`. The question I have, how do I get the proper cert/key/ca files for cassandra-driver on node? I've tried exporting based on feeds I've found, but there's no good tutorials anywhere.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sslOptions = {
    key : fs.readFileSync('node.key'),
    cert : fs.readFileSync('node.cert')
    ca : [fs.readFileSync('clusterCA.pem')]
};

var authProvider = new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra');
var client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints: ['x.x.x.x'],
  authProvider: authProvider,
  sslOptions : sslOptions
});
```

Reading through other Java connection tutorials, I could just include my keystore, and on the Ruby connector, it says it only needs the server certificate.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: PEBKAC error ;(

Answer (score 2):

Oh man...it's those types of days...

I had it trying to connect to the wrong IP. I think we all need to take a step back from the keyboard every once in a while!